# How can I get back to level 5 in Legends of Grimrock, once I've gone to level 6?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've been tromping around on level 6 ("Trapped") for a while, looking for a way to get back to level 5.

I have more or less completed the level, since I can access the stairs down at the end of the Sequentis area, but I can't find a way back up.

I did find

> a secret staircase in the Halls of Fire (in the long hallway with the fireball-shooting head) that led back up to level 5. However this leads me into a room containing two fire elementals that blocks me off from the rest of level 5.

In short, I can't seem to figure out how to get back to the main area of level 5 and above. I'm trying to kill some green slimes I passed up earlier.

Is it too late to go back, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I have not played the game, but I wonder if it might be by design that you are having trouble leaving a level called "Trapped"

Comment: I know this can definitely be reopened, but I just ran around with my party through that level and I can't figure out which switch may have caused it to reopen. It may have been a side effect of going down to level 7. I'd go down to 7 and then maybe come back up and check after a few minutes to see if that auto-unlocks it.

Comment: @murgatroid Previous conversations with the developers have suggested that you can never really "get stuck", as it were. Also, you're not really "trapped" on this level since indeed you can get down to level 7 and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out through trial and error and some experimentation with save files. Once you

> step on the plate at the start of level 7,

the grate at the start of level 6 will raise and you can get back to the higher levels.

Notice that merely

> visiting level 7 through the basement stairs or falling through pits

is not sufficient to raise the grate at the start of level 6.